# Terminator T-1000 possible in reality?

Tags: technology, warfare, science-fiction

I've seen all the [Terminator] movies (Which I always loved because of the technology).

**To clarify what I mean (I've added a reference for who wants to look at):**
[The Terminator](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(franchise)) is a killing machine (There are variants of Robots and Cyborgs).
The T-1 to T-800 are almost fully mechanical while the T-1000 is partly liquid metal (Or polyalloy).

The T-1000 is a cyborg which has a solid metal and liquid metal form which can be switched between whenever the intelligence wants to. This makes it possible to go through fences and such. It also can absorb bullets and even recover from grenades. As the liquid metal tends to go to the bigger group like most liquid do. The only two weaknesses are extremely cold to freeze it or extremely high temperature to melt the metal completely.

About the 'Mimic PolyAlloy' it is a substance which can mimic every weapon or even human except explosives and such by interacting with it.

Would it be possible to do so in reality and basically create a Terminator ([T-1000](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-1000)) in reallife, I am interested If it's possible and how/why.

Comment: There is a SciFi/Fantasy SE for people wondering about all kinds of weird stuff like that concerning movies and American pop culture, so this is the wrong forum. If you want to know how one would construct such a "Terminator" in reality, you should specify that, but I don't think this is the case. I still gave you an upvote because you are the first person on earth to say they actually loved the 3rd and even the 4th one.

Comment: This sounds like a question about *Terminator* rather than a world-building question, you might want to take this to SFF.SE instead.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited it to make it a bit more relevant. Tell me If not.

Comment: I feel like this still needs narrowing down, as at the moment you're asking about six different questions. I'd focus on just the last one - whether it's possible to make a Terminator in real life - and remove the others.

Comment: @Azoraqua Not everyone has seen (or in my case understood/not fell asleep during) those movies. Since asking how a particular thing was done in a movie is off topic here, you should explain that part. What is a T-3000? Was it that liquid woman? What do you mean by Nanbots injected into a human? I thought Terminators were machines? You would also have to answer your own questions about the movie first before this belongs here

Comment: @Azoraqua , what you should ask is not "Is it possible" but rather "What could prevent this from being possible?". Short answer: nothing we know of so far.

Comment: I've edited it to give it some more explanation about the machines itself.

Comment: I think you absolutely have to decide which one you want to know about. Those 3 types you are mentioning right now face completely different difficulties. Btw, why not make 3 topics, each discussing each type of terminator?

Comment: I've specified which one specific, I chose for the T-1000.

Comment: It's getting there. I would focus the question now and drop anything about the other terminators. In order to answer your question currently one has to 1) know the terminator stuff very well and b) know a lot about sciency stuff. You can eliminate (1) by telling us what exactly this "mimic polyalloy one" is. I'm sure they already have a pseudo-sciency/technobabble explanation in "cannon". This would make the group of people able to have suggestions how this might work larger by I suspect a factor of 100. It would also save the 1% some time and effort to explain what the T1000 is first.

Comment: I removed all irrelevant details except those of the T-1000. And for technical reference kept the older ones as reference. Also changed the title to reflect the context.

Comment: In addition I added a short but almost fully explanation about what the T-1000 is and can do.

Comment: @Raditz_35 [Questions based in movies can be on topic.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3141/29)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Absolutely not what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not yet. Perhaps never.

There are real-world robots. Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigDog). Or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roomba). They don't have the capabilities of a Terminator *yet*. Surely they will get better in the future, but I'm not sure if they will ever become "liquid metal" nanotech as shown in the movies.

Comment: I like your explanation of why you think this might never happen. Never thought about it like that

Comment: @Raditz_35, I didn't explain about nanotech because we're not **remotely** there yet. First we have to go from something like the Legged Squad Support System to a T-800, which is merely much better what we have now.